# problem in converting my image to grayScale with cvtColor() function

Tags: python, opencv

Unable to import video media folder into program to convert to gray-scale.
this is my code

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("‪C:/Users/azert/Desktop/LONDON WALK _ Oxford Street to Carnaby Street _ England(240P)_1.mp4")
body=cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/azert/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml")
while  1:   
    r,img=cap.read()
    gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    bd=body.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,2)
    for(x,y,w,h) in bd :
       cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1) 
       for(x1,y1,w1,h1) in bd:
             distance=[]
             d1=w-w1
             d2=h-h1
             d=math.sqrt((d1**2)+(d2**2))
             distance.append(d)
       s=len(distance)
       N=0.5
       for i in range (s):
             if( distance[i]<N) :
                      cv2.line(img,(w,h),(w1,h1),(255,0,0),3,8)
                      cv2.imshow("image",img)
    if  cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-609b19b26536> in <module>
      7 
      8     r,img=cap.read()
----> 9     gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
     10     bd=body.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,2)
     11     for(x,y,w,h) in bd :

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-52oirelq\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: I think that your image is empty.

Comment: no it's not it works for me with this code  
import cv2
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/azert/Desktop/projetMadani/Person.mp4")
body=cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/azert/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml")
while  1:
    r,img=cap.read()
 
    gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    bd=body.detectMultiScale(gray,1.2,1)
    for(x,y,w,h) in bd :
       cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1) 
       cv2.imshow("img",img)  
    if  cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

Comment: i think the problem is in the second part in which i try to calculate for each rectangle its distance with other rectangles and compare it to N to draw a line if the distance is inférior to N

Comment: You call `len(distance)` outside the for loop, so It is not initialized.

Comment: can you tell me please what does x and y means in bd it's said that they are the rectagle coordinates can you draw for me a rectangle and place x and y in it and show me how the rectangle function draw a rectangle ,i will be very gratefull

Comment: I think it is done that way: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:83f999a9-8576-4134-99c4-5f430baebd31

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when first argument of `cvtColor` function is absent. Your program doesn't quit when video stream is over (because ov `while 1`).

check if img exists

```
r,img=cap.read()
if img:
    #do thing
else:
    #exit
```

and better use it with

```
while cap.isOpened():
    #rest of code
```

Comment: when i used while cap.isOpened():  it does not show me any results

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention three possible issues with your code:

- Possible Issue#1:

---

- Make sure you define your path correctly.
- The reason I'm writing this is because generally `haarcascades`'s xmls are located in `<your-path>data/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml`
- When I saw `data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml` in your code, I though I should warn you about the correct-path.
- Possible Issue#2:

---

- There is a reason `cap.read()` returns two variables.
- You should check whether the image returns a `frame` or `None`by using:

  - ```py
    if r:
        gray= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        ...
        ..
        .
    ```
  - `r` is a boolean variable, if it returns `False` it means frame is not extracted from the current video.
- Possible Issue#3:

---

- opencv reads images in `BGR` mode. Therefore when you are converting frame you should use `cv2.BGR2GRAY` instead of `cv2.RGB2GRAY`.

Rest of the code seems ok.